# Absolute Location Header for HTTP 201 with Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I've got a *reactive* REST controller (with Spring WebFlux) and when performing POST requests I want to set an *absolute* link to the resource that has just been created into the mandatory `Location` header. I'm only able to create *relative* links so far. Adding `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest` or `org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange` as *additional* method parameters in any order to retrieve host information etc. resulted in HTTP 415 responses without reaching the controller method.

```
@RequestMapping("/v1/stuffs")
@RestController
public class StuffController {

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Stuff>> createStuff(
            @Valid @NotNull @RequestBody Mono<Stuff> stuff) {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().pathSegment("v1", "stuffs", id.toString()).build().toUri();

        // ugly approach with help of spring-hateoas, which resulted in a relative link too
        // URI uri = WebFluxLinkBuilder.linkTo(WebFluxLinkBuilder.methodOn(StuffController.class).getStuff(id)).withSelfRel().toMono().block().toUri();

        return stuff
            .map(it -> stuffService.create(id, it))
            .map(it -> ResponseEntity.created(uri).build());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Stuff>> getStuff(@NotNull @PathVariable("id") UUID id) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `UriComponentsBuilder componentsBuilder` to the controller's method signature should make it work:

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Stuff>> createStuff(
    @Valid @NotNull @RequestBody Mono<Stuff> stuff,
    UriComponentsBuilder componentsBuilder) {
    ...
    URI uri = componentsBuilder.path("/v1/stuffs/{id}").buildAndExpand(id.toString()).toUri();
    ...
}
```